# Cannot find symbol in Java 7 OOP

Tags: java

The error is occurring under `public class ModemTester` under `CableModem` and `DslModem`. I'm new to programming and the book, Sam's learn Java in 24 hours, I'm going through has this exercise, listing 10.2-5, I cannot figure out. All of you experts out there fill me with your wisdom ^-^. Thank You

```
public class Modem {
    int speed;

    public void displaySpeed() {
        System.out.println("Speed: " + speed);
   }
}

public class CableModem extends Modem {
    String method = "cable connection";

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Connecting to the Internet.....");
        System.out.println("Using a " + method);
    }
}

public class DslModem extends Modem {
    String method = "DSL phone connection";

    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Connecting to the Internet.....");
        System.out.println("Using a " + method);
    }
}

public class ModemTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        CableModem surfBoard = new CableModem();
        DslModem gateway = new DslModem();
        surfBoard.speed = 500000;
        gateway.speed = 400000;
        System.out.println("Trying the cable modem:");
        surfBoard.displaySpeed();
        surfBoard.connect();
        System.out.println("Trying the DSL modem:");
        gateway.displaySpeed();
        gateway.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: What symbol, and what line number?

Comment: *Sam's learn Java in 24 hours* -> Seriously? Then how about this - [Teach yourself Programming in 10 years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html). Huge difference yeah? Please pick a good book, or follow Oracle Tutorial. The above book will only confuse you.

Comment: Put all `.java` files together, in a folder. Then go to this location using the Terminal/CommandPrompt, then compile using `javac *.java` now run using `java ModemTester`. That is the most simplest way I can think of :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the imput. The Symbol is CableModem and DslModem and it is lines 3 and 4 under ModemTester

Comment: @RohitJain I just finish reading your suggested article, and am more confused. I thought programming books was a good place to get basic knowledge of programming outside of going to school. Btw I prefer not to go to school. Java is the language I want to learn first. I am self taught and very motivated. Where should I start?

Comment: @user2657481. You should certainly choose a better book. You see, you can't learn Java in 24 hours. At least I can't. You can start with Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java".

Comment: @RohitJain I will look into getting that book. I just want to make it clear I am not in any rush to learn Java, I just want a good learning tool.

Comment: @RohitJain just found Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" downloading it now. I am open to any other book suggestions anyone else has.

Comment: @Shio : You need to add `import` statement at the start of your `ModemTester` class :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the classes in the same package/folder? Because the `speed` variable is package-private, meaning it will only be visible to `ModemTester` if it's in the same package as `Modem`.

You can test this by setting `int speed` to `public int speed` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: As far as I know they are not in the same package/folder.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow to have more then one top-level public class per file